# how to split value in Ansible with delimiter

Tags: python, filter, split, ansible, jinja2

I am setting a fact in Ansible and that variable has a value with hyphens, like this "**dos-e1-south-209334567829102380**". i want to split , so i  only get **"dos-e1-south"**

Here is the play

```
- set_fact:
    config: "{{ asg.results|json_query('[*].launch_configuration_name') }}"

- debug:
    var: config
```

Comment: not sure how to use it exactly. throwing errors. i am using jinja filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

another option is ansibles regular expression filter, you find here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters

```
vars:
  var: dos-e1-south-209334567829102380
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ var | regex_replace("^(.*)-[^-]+$", "\\1") }}'
```

has the same result:

```
"msg": "dos-e1-south"
```

#### Explanation for the regex:

```
^(.*)
```

keep everything from the start of the string in the first backreference

```
-[^-]+$
```

find the last "-" followed by non-"-" characters till the end of string.

```
\\1
```

replaces the string with the first backreference.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 20):

An option would be to use *`split()`*. The tasks below

```yaml
    vars:
      var1: dos-e1-south-209334567829102380
    tasks:
      - set_fact:
          var2: "{{ var1.split('-') }}"
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ var2.0 }}-{{ var2.1 }}-{{ var2.2 }}"
```

give

```yaml
    "msg": "dos-e1-south"
```

---

To concatenate the items, it's also possible to use *`join()`*. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ var2[0:3] | join('-') }}"
```