# Target multiple hosts with different configurations

Tags: ansible

I have checked some similar questions but those questions don't answer my question.

I have three hosts:

```
   - host_abc_01
   - host_def_01
   - host_ghi_01
```

I want to create directories this way:

```
   - host_abc_01:
     - d:\abc\dir1\dir2

   - host_def_01:
     - d:\def\dir1\dir2

   - host_ghi_01:
     - d:\ghi\dir1\dir2
```

the only different is the directory name. the sub directories have the same name.

Instead of creating three different roles with own tasks and varfiles, is there any way to achieve this in one play?

```
   - name: create project directory
      win_file:
        path: '{{ projects_volume }}\{{ item.proj_name }}\{{ some_dir }}'
      state: directory
      loop:
        - { proj_name: 'abc', when: "'abc' in inventory_hostname" }
        - { proj_name: 'def', when: "'def' in inventory_hostname" }
        - { proj_name: 'ghi', when: "'ghi' in inventory_hostname" }
```

But all directories are created on all hosts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe not the answer you look for, but you can create 3 host_vars files :

inventory/host_vars/host_abc_01

```
proj_name: abc
```

inventory/host_vars/host_def_01

```
proj_name: def
```

inventory/host_vars/host_ghi_01

```
proj_name: ghi
```

then your role would be:

```
- name: create project directory
  win_file:
    path: '{{ projects_volume }}\{{ proj_name }}\{{ some_dir }}'
    state: directory
```

You can organize vars as you like, just look at :
[Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: KIS DRY : keep it simple, don't repeat yourself !

Answer (score 0):

You can [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187028/how-to-split-value-in-ansible-with-delimiter) *inventory_hostname*

```
path: 'd:\{{ inventory_hostname.split("_")[1] }}\dir1\dir2'
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But indeed not working the way it should be. At least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

a more generic approach if the subfolder name is not part of the hostname

```
vars:
path_part:
  'host_01': 'abc'
  'host_02': 'def'
  'host_03': 'ghi'

tasks:
- name: create project directory
  win_file:
    path: '{{ projects_volume }}\{{ path_part[inventory_hostname] }}\{{ some_dir }}'
    state: directory
```

Comment: thanks but i will go for tassinp solution. as i can put as much vars as i want in the host_vars files.